# Why is this basic json call not working?

Tags: ajax, vb.net, json, model-view-controller

The following JSON call always hits the AJAX error handler, and I can't figure out why:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '<%= Url.Action("MyTest", "Detail") %>',
    dataType: "json",
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        alert(xhr + " | " + status + " | " + error);
    },
    success: function (json) {
        alert(json);
    }
});
```

All I get is `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) http://localhost:4497/Detail/MyTest?_=1320681138394`

When I set a breakpoint in the controller, I can see that it's being reached, so I'm not sure where the request is falling down. Here's the action in the DetailController:

```
Function MyTest() As JsonResult
    Return Json("Hello")
End Function
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What happens when you access `http://localhost:4497/Detail/MyTest` directly?

Comment: Try visiting "http://localhost:4497/Detail/MyTest?_=1320681138394" directly in your web browser to get more info about the exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jQuery error handler is fired because it failed to parse the returned page as valid JSON. Since you get 500 internal server error, the page most likely doesn't contain valid JSON.

Load this page in your browser and fix it until it gives valid json:

```
http://localhost:4497/Detail/MyTest
```

After it is giving valid json in the browser, try the jQuery ajax call.

I have no idea of even the basic functionality of VB.NET but can you make so that the only thing that is printed on http://localhost:4497/Detail/MyTest is like:

```
print( '{"message":"hello"}' );
```

If the only thing the page is outputting is `{"message":"hello"}` then json error handler will not fire

Comment: Bingo! Loading that URL via the browser revealed the true error message: "This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request. To allow GET requests, set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet." All I had to do was return "Json("Hello", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)" in the controller action and it worked just fine. Thanks!